# Screen sharing in C#

Tags: c#, screenshot, image-compression, screensharing

i want to do a simple screen share software in C#, i read many many codes and ideas about it and got really confused.
My idea so far is to take screenshots (30fps), compress them, and sending them to the server - first i want to know if thats a good idea.
Second thing is that i tried some code parts that i found in the internet and it did not go well, i need help with the screenshot (simple code who deal with bitmap and stuff, the quality doesn't have to be so good, more attention needs to be paid to efficiency - i read about JPG).
I new to this image business, so if you got ideas for compress it will be great.

there is a code that's i tried:

```
private void print(Bitmap BM, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphicsObj = e.Graphics; //Get graphics from the event
        graphicsObj.DrawImage(BM, 0, 0); // or "e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 60, 10);"
        graphicsObj.Dispose();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle totalSize = Rectangle.Empty;

        foreach (Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)
            totalSize = Rectangle.Union(totalSize, s.Bounds);

        Bitmap screenShotBMP = new Bitmap(totalSize.Width, totalSize.Height, PixelFormat.
            Format32bppArgb);

        Graphics screenShotGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenShotBMP);

        screenShotGraphics.CopyFromScreen(totalSize.X, totalSize.Y, 0, 0, totalSize.Size,
            CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

        screenShotGraphics.Dispose();
        print(screenShotBMP, e);
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
    }
```

I dont sure if it the best way (this code look not promising, and i dont sure if its good for my needs).
And last thing guys, i want to pack the compressed images into pack of 30 to send it, what should i do in this case?

Comment: Update: i found this jpg encoder, and i will use him: JpegBitmapEncoder Class

Comment: looks fine to me, but i would only get the screenshot for one screen. Also why do you wanna send the screenshots in batches of 30, you will have 1 sec delay then...

Comment: So how can I send the pictures? one frame per sec